# reversing a linked list in groups of a given size

Tags: c, algorithm, linked-list

I am solving a problem of reversing a linked list in groups of given size and the algorithm i am using is as follows:

1) Reverse the first sub-list of size k. While reversing i kept the track of the next node and previous node. Let the pointer to the next node be next and pointer to the previous node be prev & pointer to current node is ptr.

2) head = reverse(next, k)-Recursively call for rest of the list

3) return prev which is the new head of the reversed list

My code sample is:

```
struct node *reverse(struct node *start,int k)
{
    struct node *prev,*ptr,*next;
    prev=NULL;
    ptr=start;
    int count=0;
    while(count<k && ptr!=NULL)
    {
        next=ptr->link;
        ptr->link=prev;
        prev=ptr;
        ptr=next;
        count++;
    }

    if(next!=NULL)//recursive call
    start=reverse(next,k);

    return prev;
}
```

But my output is only reversing the first half of the list!

for eg: If my list is : 98 74 94 857 8 7

```
    My output is : 94 74 98(The rest is not being displayed)
```

Where am i wrong?..Is this method correct?

Comment: What does "reversing in groups" mean? Reverse each group, while keeping the relative order of the groups unchanged? Or reverse the relative order of the groups, while keeping ordering inside each group unchanged?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you make the recursive call:

```
if(next!=NULL)//recursive call
  start=reverse(next,k);

return prev;
```

you save the results of the recursive call in `start`, which you never refer to again. The pointer expires when control passes from the function, and the results of the recursive call (that is, anything beyond the first `k` elements) are lost. You must append these results to the reversed sub-list before returning.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(next!=NULL)//recursive call
 start->next=reverse(next,k);

return prev;
```

This would work next has stored location for the (k+1)th node.When we do start->next (k+1)th node becomes new head and